# Ordenar itens de uma Collection a partir de um valor pré-definido

Tags: php, laravel, classificação, laravel-eloquent, collection

Eu tenho uma `Collection` do Eloquent e gostaria de ordená-la por dois campos ao mesmo tempo sendo um deles um valor pré-definido.

Ex.:  esta `Collection` tem vários objetos do tipo `Categoria` e eu quero ordená-la de forma que as categorias que tenham a propriedade `slug` igual a `"solicitacoes"` fiquem no início e quero que as demais fiquem em ordem alfabética.

Eu sei que o método `sort` pode receber um *callback* para ordenar a coleção e tentei fazer (dentre outras coisas) isto

```
$sorted = $categorias->sort(function ($item, $next) {
    return $item->slug === 'solicitacoes' ? -1 :            
           strcmp($item->descricao, $next->descricao);
});
```

Porém a ordenação não deu muito certo, desconsiderando as categorias com `slug = "solicitacoes"` ficou em ordem alfabética, o problema é que as supracitadas não ficaram no início.

Comment: `strcmp` devolve a diferença dos caracteres no que difere. Exemplo `strcmp` de `"A"` para `"Z"` devolve `-25`. Aconselhava a experimentar com `-100` para ficar antes de todas.

Comment: @Isac Tentei com `-10000` e deu na mesma.

Comment: @DjalmaManfrin Não entendi absolutamente nada do que você quis dizer.

Comment: Se passar os dados ordenados de forma alfabéticas para as `collection`  e depois usar o `$sorted = $categorias->sortBy('solicitacoes')`, qual resultado sairia da`collection $categorias` ? Recomentei porque não conseguia alterar o comentário anterior.

Comment: @DjalmaManfrin Não existe `sortBy('solicitacoes')` uma vez que `solicitacoes` é um valor de `slug`. Se bem entendi você quer que eu traga os resultados do banco já ordenados alfabeticamente e depois tente fazer a minha ordenação personalizada, se é isto, não adianta porque a segunda ordenação desfaz a primeira.

Comment: E `dd($item->slug)` apresenta o quê ? para um que seja uma solicitação

Comment: @Isac Apresenta o valor do campo `slug`. Pode ser `solicitacoes`, `downloads`, qualquer coisa. Para que seja uma solicitação o campo retorna  `solicitacoes`.

Comment: A minha questão era mais para ter a certeza que está a entrar no `if` e retornar `-1`/`-10000` para as solicitações, não vá ter algum espaço ou caractere esquisito que faça a condição não entrar, ou até ser de tipo diferente uma vez que se está a utilizar `===`

Comment: Ah sim, ele tá certinho. Nenhum carácter estranho nem nada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizando o `Collection`, eu substitui o método `sort` por `SortBy`.

O método `sortBy` faz com que, internamente, o Laravel compare os valores de acordo com os tipos, através do `sort` (algo parecido como que você fez na pergunta usando o `sort`).

Assim, podemos checar no `sortBy` se o valor de `slug` é equivalente à `"solicitações"`. Caso seja, retornamos `NULL` para que esse item seja colocado acima. Caso contrário, retornamos `"descricao"` para ordenar por esse campo.

Veja:

```
$sorted = $categorias->sortBy(function ($item)
{
     return $item->slug === 'solicitacoes' ? null : $item->descricao;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Com o método [`sort`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-sort) e sua regra não tem como, o que deve ser feito é um `where` e depois um `union` com exclusão:

```
$sort = $categorias->where('slug', 'solicitacoes')
            ->sortBy('descricao')
            ->union($categorias->where('slug','<>', 'solicitacoes')->sortBy('descricao'))
            ->all();
```

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Collection - where](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-where)
- [Collection - union](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-union)
- [Collection - sortBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-sortby)
- [Collection - all](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-all)
- [Colleciton - sort](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-sort)

Comment: Boa saída, mas pensei que tivesse algo mais legível.

Comment: Bom @LINQ não vejo alternativa quando é para ordenar inclusive dois campos que é o seu caso, se ordenar um somente até dá, mas, o que eu fiz vai ordernar os dois campos e isso que acho que não ficou claro na sua pergunta.!